# Instance changed when trying to access method of property

Tags: angular, typescript

I'd like to apply the forEach() method on an instance's property which is of type 'QueryList'.
But when trying to access any of the property's methods, the instance seems to be changed.

What am I doing wrong?

**app.component.html**

```
<switcher>
   <item label="Male" value="male"></item>
   <item label="Female" value="female"></item>
</switcher>
```

**switcher.component,ts**

```
...
@Component({
   selector: 'switcher',
   template: `
      <button *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"
      (click)="selectItem(item)">{{item.label}}</button>
   `,
})

export class SwitcherComponent {
   @ContentChildren(ItemComponent) items: ItemComponent;

   selectItem(selectedItem): void {
      console.log(this.constructor.name); //SwitcherComponent
      console.log(this.items.constructor.name); //QueryList

      this.items.forEach(function(){}) //ERROR: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'ItemComponent'
      for (let item of this.items) {}  //ERROR: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'ItemComponent'
   }
}
```

**item.component.ts** (not too important)

```
...
@Component({
   selector: 'item',
   template: `<button><ng-content></ng-content></button>`
})

export class ItemComponent {
   @Input() label: string;
   @Input() value: any;
   selected: false;
}
```

Comment: instance changed means ?

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: @Vega using "@ContentChildren", I've added the component to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've typed items as "**an** ItemComponent", not a QueryList of ItemComponents. TypeScript takes your word for it (even if your code is showing that's not its assigned type) so it's right that that type has no forEach.

```
@ContentChildren(ItemComponent) items: QueryList<ItemComponent>;
```

Comment: Stupid me, thanks a lot!
You solution threw the same error, but when omitting the type declaration at all it works!

Comment: That was a nice catch btw !